# Plot Series of Exp(x) about x=0 to order 12

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

Hello I want to Plot the  Series of Exp(x) about x=0 to order 12 but it returns an error when i use the function Plot.

```
res = Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}];
Plot[res, {x, -3, 3}]
```

How can I do? Are there many ways to plot them? If yes, which are they ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show what you got so far.

Comment: In[36]:= res = Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]

In[38]:= Plot[res, {x, -3, 3}]
During evaluation of In[38]:= SeriesData::ssdn: Attempt to evaluate a series at the number -2.99988. Returning Indeterminate. >>

During evaluation of In[38]:= SeriesData::ssdn: Attempt to evaluate a series at the number -2.87743. Returning Indeterminate. >>

During evaluation of In[38]:= SeriesData::ssdn: Attempt to evaluate a series at the number -2.75498. Returning Indeterminate. >>

During evaluation of In[38]:= General::stop: Further output of SeriesData::ssdn will be suppressed during this calculation. >

Comment: Edit your question accordingly, don't post crucial yet lengthy pieces of code in the comments - it's unreadable.

Comment: Moreover, [read the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/). Specifically, in the help for [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html?q=Series), under Applications, you have examples showing how to deal with the output of `Series`, particularly how to plot it.

Comment: In[36]:= res = Series[Exp[x], {x, 0,10}]                                       ln[38]:=Plot[res, {x, -3, 3}]                                                                  Attempt to evaluate a series at the number -2.9998774285714287`. \
Returning Indeterminate. >>                                                              Further output of SeriesData::ssdn will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: Please upvote tablecircle's answer and accept it if it is the perfect answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [Series](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) first.
I don't know which one do you want
...
but your question probably duplicated.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Normal[Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 12}]]], {x, 0, 100}]
```

or

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Normal[Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, n}]], {n, 12}]], {x, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: Thanx it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You did not pay attention to Corey's comments. Your code can be made to not display the error messages by adding Normal to the end of the series.

```
res = Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]//Normal;
Plot[res, {x, -3, 3}]
```