# Plot Taylor Polynomial

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

I am trying to plot `Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, 5}]` using Mathematica by adding this input, however its not plotting.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Normal[Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, 5}]], {5, 20}]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: you want to plot series  `Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, 5}]` ? then try this:  `ser = Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, 5}] // Normal;
     Plot[ser, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: See the 2nd answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130464/plot-series-of-expx-about-x-0-to-order-12

Comment: Does replacing the `Table` with `Table[Normal[Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, d}]], {d, 5, 20}]` make it right?

Answer (score 1):

You may do one thing of two: either (1) plot the expansion directly as a regular function, or (2) transform it into a list and then plot it as a list. You mixed up these two operations.

If you want to go for the first possibility, you operate more or less like it is described in the comment of @math. A slightly different version of the same is as follows:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Normal[Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, 5}]]], {x, 0.1, 2}]
```

[image]

In the case, you want to exploit the second possibility, you first create a table of numbers. Its elements must have the structure `{x,y}`, where `x` is the variable value, and `y`is the one of the function. Then it has the form

```
Table[{x, Normal[Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, 5}]]} /. x -> x1, {x1, 
  0.1, 2, 0.1}]

(* {{0.1, 3.78405}, {0.2, 2.85936}, {0.3, 2.17335}, {0.4, 1.66959}, {0.5,
   1.30225}, {0.6, 1.03488}, {0.7, 0.839301}, {0.8, 0.694365}, {0.9, 
  0.584794}, {1., 0.5}, {1.1, 0.4329}, {1.2, 0.378735}, {1.3, 
  0.333892}, {1.4, 0.29472}, {1.5, 0.256348}, {1.6, 0.211505}, {1.7, 
  0.14934}, {1.8, 0.05424}, {1.9, -0.0953542}, {2., -0.328125}}   *)
```

Note that after expanding I replaced `x` by `x1` to avoid a conflict of the iterators.

Now this list may be wrapped by the plotting operator. In this case, however, this must be the `ListPlot`, rather than `Plot`.

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, Normal[Series[1/(x^2 + x), {x, 1, 5}]]} /. 
   x -> x1, {x1, 0.1, 2, 0.01}]]
```

This yields the following plot:

[image]

They look pretty much the same, as it should be.

Have fun!